# Put the logic to create and update cart item on client side or server side?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using: NodeJs, MySQL, React, Express, Axios.

Which options is the best practice: opsi 1 or 2 ?

Thank you very much /\ :)

**Opsi 1. do the logic on SERVER side**

a. client side

- I don't check whether cartId+productId already created on the cartItems table
- I don't call http post to create "cartId+productId" on the cartItems table if it hasn't created yet.
- I use property: "change" instead of quantity.
  Just wondering would it be better if I change the code by getting the item using "http get" and using "quantity: item.quantity + 1" instead of "change property".
- The code is so simple, only two lines of code

```
async addToCart(product) {
   const cartId = await getOrCreateCartId();
   await http.put(`${apiEndpoint}/${cartId}/items/${product.id}`, { change: 1 });
}
```

b. Server side

- I am not really sure if it's a best practice to "create a new record" using "http put" instead of "http post"

```
router.put('/carts/:cartId/items/:productId', async (req, res) => {
   // validate req.body, if not valid, return 400
   // validate req.params.cartId, if not found, return 404
   // validate req.params.productId, if not found, return 404

   let shoppingCartItem = await ShoppingCartItem.query().findById([
       req.params.cartId,
       req.params.productId,
   ]);

   if (!shoppingCartItem)
      shoppingCartItem = await ShoppingCartItem.query().insertAndFetch({
      cartId: req.params.cartId,
      productId: req.params.productId,
      quantity: req.body.change,
    });
    else
       shoppingCartItem = await shoppingCartItem
      .$query()
      .increment('quantity', req.body.change);

    res.send('cart item created / quantity updated');
});
```

**Opsi 2. do the logic on CLIENT side**

a. client side

- I feel the code become hard to read

```
async function addToCart(product) {
  const cartId = await getOrCreateCartId();

  try {
    const { data: item } = await http.get(
      `${apiEndpoint}/${cartId}/items/${product.id}`
    );

    await http.put(`${apiEndpoint}/${cartId}/items/${product.id}`, {
      productId: product.id,
      quantity: item.quantity + 1,
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    await http.post(`${apiEndpoint}/${cartId}/items`, {
      productId: product.id,
      quantity: 1,
    });
  }
```

b. server side

- I add 2 new route handler: http get & http post
- Http Post, only create a new record
- Http Put, ONLY update a record
- Http Get, so the client can check whether the item exists or not

```
router.get('/:cartId/items/:productId', async (req, res) => {
  const shoppingCartItem = await ShoppingCartItem.query().findById([
    req.params.cartId,
    req.params.productId,
  ]);

  if (!shoppingCartItem) return res.status(404).send('The shopping cart item with the given ID was not found.');

  res.send(shoppingCartItem);
});

router.post('/:id/items', async (req, res) => {
   // validate req.body, if not valid, return 400
   // validate req.params.cartId, if not found, return 404
   // validate req.params.productId, if not found, return 400
   // validate req.params.cartId+productId, if found, return 400, Shopping Cart Item already added

   const  shoppingCartItem = await ShoppingCartItem.transaction(async (trx) => {
   await shoppingCart
      .$query(trx)
      .patch({ updatedAt: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') });

   return await ShoppingCartItem.query(trx).insertAndFetch({
      cartId: req.params.id,
      productId: req.body.productId,
      quantity: req.body.quantity,
    });
  });

  res.send(shoppingCartItem);
});

router.put('/:cartId/items/:productId', async (req, res) => {
   // validate req.body, if not valid, return 400
   // validate req.params.cartId, if not found, return 404
   // validate req.params.productId, if not found, return 400
   // validate req.params.cartId+productId, if not found, return 404, The shopping cart item with the given ID was not found.

   await ShoppingCartItem.transaction(async (trx) => {
   await shoppingCart
      .$query(trx)
      .patch({ updatedAt: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') });

   return await shoppingCartItem
      .$query(trx)
      .patchAndFetch({ quantity: req.body.quantity });
  });

  res.send('cart item created / quantity updated');
});
```

Comment: Most online shops I know of do the add-to-cart logic on the client end only. Put that info in a cookie or local storage. No need to waste server time on that until they check out. Thats how amazon works, I think. My cart sometimes even has different items in it if I'm on a different computer.

Comment: I don't really know but I think it typically depends on whether or not you're 'logged in'. If you are, then the data is stored in a database. Otherwise the data is stored in session cookies.